# Maintain unique value for DynamoDB partition key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, key, unique

I'm new to "DynamoDB" and wanting to know best practice to maintaining unique partition key value when you add records to a table.

With my existing experience related to SQL, primary keys are normally maintained by the system with identity columns or via a trigger.  I've searched through various forums and "AWS" documentation, but did not find any specifics.  Do you manually determine the existence of partition key value or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

In DynamoDB  the querying is flexibility is limited when compared to SQL. So the schema as well as partition key / sort key should be designed to make the most common and important queries as fast as possible.  You can find some generic best practices here

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/best-practices.html
2. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/

If you can provide better context on the use case that you are trying to use DynamoDB, you should get more pointed answere